# a simple loop string in java needs review

Tags: java, string, loops, return

so ive done coding before but for some reason i cant seem to figure this one out and i keep over thinking the solution. so to summarize, the first method is supposed to return 1 oys, the second method should return 3 oys, and the third methods needs to return 5 oys. i've linked an screen shot to the project, it isn't for school or anything like that, just a friend trying to reteach me java, and then eventually full stacks sql. i mainly have dealt with android. [project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHc7R.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots as reference, but rather post your code here in a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why is there 3 differents methods ? What is the 'x' parameter used for ?

Comment: I also don't fully understand your question here. Do you ask how to build the string to return?

Comment: so what my friends wants me to do is use a loop to return oys ill post the code real quick

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L927wasf/

Comment: So, what exactly is your question? Where are you stuck right now? Why don't your friends assist you? I can't really help you if you don't clarify where you are stuck.

Comment: im stuck at the loop string where im only allowed to use 1 return for the 3 loop strings. he doesn't want to help me because i have to figure it out. but i keep overthinking the problem, i've solved all the problems so far and i've been stumped for 3 days on trying to google how to use a loop to return the "oys"

Comment: like i know i need to add on the second method to make the console print out oys oys oys, instead of null.

Comment: ```Java
String answer = "oys";
for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
   answer += " oys";
}
return answer;
```
This will print "oys" x times, where x is your parameter.
But the question is not clear.

Comment: Well, create a string and a loop which runs `x`times, and for each loop add `oy` to your existing string. After your loop finished, return the string.

Comment: so sorry for not being able to clarify my question, i feel really dumb right now for not being able to figure this thing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you need to build a string in the `loopedOyMethod()` and return it. You can do this by using a while loop or a for loop.

while loop:-

```java
String s = "";
while (x>0)
{
   s = s + "Oy" + " ";
   x = x - 1;
}
return s;
```

For loop:-

```java
String s = "";
for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
{
   s = s + "Oy" + " ";
}
return s;
```